# How can you calculate featurematrix in featuretools more specific to avoid long running?

Tags: featuretools

I want to calculate a feature of second order (depth = 2). Because of the entity structure the feature matrix calculation need to calculate so many combination that the calculation takes "years".

Can one more specify via a rule settings the list of features to be calculated?

I have a Customer Table (cid, ...) with fixed data (i.e. birth date) related to each customer.
Additional I have two (A and B) different tables (cid, MonthlyReportPeriod, ...) derived from customer monthly behavior (i.e. #orders) on different products.
The wanted features of second order is for instance the wighted sum in time of orders for each behavior table.

When I calculate the features using just one behavior table (A) > 1000 feature are calculated. I think when I use the two in one shot I have two many combination.

```py
es = ft.EntitySet(id = 'ES_PRA')
es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id = 'Customer', dataframe = Customer, 
                              index = 'cid')
es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id = 'A', 
                              dataframe = A,
                              make_index = True,
                              index = 'AID',
                              time_index = 'MonthlyReportPeriod')

es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id = 'B', 
                              dataframe = B,
                              make_index = True,
                              index = 'BID',
                              time_index = 'MonthlyReportPeriod')
#
r_Customer_A = ft.Relationship(es['Customer']['cid'],
                                    es['A']['cid'])
es = es.add_relationship(r_Customer_A)
#
r_Customer_B = ft.Relationship(es['Customer']['cid'],
                                    es['A']['cid'])
es = es.add_relationship(r_Customer_B)
#
seed_features=[
  ft.Feature(es["A"]['MonthlyReportPeriod'], primitive=WeightTimeUntil),
  ft.Feature(es["B"]['MonthlyReportPeriod'], primitive=WeightTimeUntil)
]
features, feature_names = ft.dfs(entityset = es, target_entity = 'Customer', 
                                 agg_primitives = ['sum','last'],
                                 seed_features=seed_features,
                                 trans_primitives = [MultiplyNumeric],
                                max_depth=2)
```

I would like to specify the aggregated primitive per column in Table A and B:

cid: -
MonthlyReportPeriod: -

(#order): sum, last, sum(WeightTimeUntil/MultiplyNumeric)

(#sales): sum, last, mean, ...

Answer (score 0):

The API of featuretools does not provide this optional setting of primitives on column level.

I posted a request on github

https://github.com/Featuretools/featuretools/issues/655